# Postgresql: partial foreign key?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints

Is it possible to create a partial foreign key (similar to partial indexes) in general sql / postgresql? I have not found a way to force referential integrity in the following case:

Table A is soft-deletable (it has a column deleted_at, which is set to a value when a row is to be marked as such), while Table B is hard-deletable (meaning we actually delete the rows)

table A:

- id
- deleted_at
- some other stuff
- partial unique index for id where deleted_at is null

table B:

- id
- deleted_at
- some other stuff
- partial unique index for id where deleted_at is null

table C:

- referred type
- referred id
- some other stuff

The rows in tables A,B,C represent objects of a certain class. The relation between them that every C needs to reference either an A or a B, marked by the value of the "type" column, and the "id" will mark which instance of the object is referred to.

What I would like to achieve is to force the integrity, so that for all rows in table C where referred type is 'MyData::A', the referred_id must match a row in table A's partial index (where deleted_at is null), similarly for B

Something like

```
ADD CONSTRAINT name FOREIGN KEY table_C(referred_id)
    REFERENCES table_A(id where deleted_at is not null)
    where referred_type = 'MyData::A'
ADD CONSTRAINT name FOREIGN KEY table_C(referred_id)
    REFERENCES table_B(id where deleted_at is not null)
    where referred_type = 'MyData::B'
```

Which obviously is bogus syntax.

If this is not possible, would it be possible to do, without messing around with the possibility to have two types of referred objects in different tables, like so:

```
    CREATE VIEW A_B_ids AS SELECT id, deleted_at From table_A
UNION SELECT id, deleted_at FROM table_B
ADD CONSTRAINT name FOREIGN KEY table_C(referred_id)
REFERENCES A_B_ids(id where deleted_at is not null)
```

Comment: Isnt possible, You have to handle that logic in a `TRIGGER`

Comment: I guess you mean for a table to be x-deletable that when a row in a table becomes in some sense non-current hard means you delete it & soft means you flag it non-current. But you should explain yourself. Ditto fr "partial unique index" & "referred type". Also the rest of your writing is unclear, please use sentences not fragments. (See [mcve].)

Comment: Hmm, I thought the meaning of soft deletable is well-defined within the community. Let me clear up the question.

Comment: Hi. Your business case involves database/sql subtyping/inheritance/polymorphism--google this faq. Your design involves a common aniti-pattern--google re many/multiple/two FKs to many/multiple/two tables. The the soft-delete aspect is additional. PS 1. You must use @xxx to notify user xxx of your comment when they are not the poster & there is more than one other commenter. I just happened to check back here. PS 2. You use "partial FK" as if it meant something--it doesn't. I see "partial index" seems to be a PostgreSQL manual term. 3. Read edit help re code block format via indenting 4 spaces

Comment: PS 3. It would help if you said the code is bogus before giving it. But this seems moot as you don't *explain* the bogus syntax, so we don't know what "something like" means. Just use enough sentences and descriptive phrases using appropriate technical terms to actually say what you mean.